# Django, Nginx, FastCGI caching problem when I change code

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I've installed Django, Nginx and FastCGI on one my servers. This is my development server and I'm having a very difficult time with the caching. Every time when I make a change I have to reboot the whole server to see the actual change. Rebooting Nginx process didn't help eithter.

So it might be Django and/or FastCGI doing the caching. I also looked at the settings.py and there is no caching set on Django.

What's the best way to make sure when I change the page code the caching gets reset automatically? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in development server? That's what it's for, to prevent you having to restart each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not `manage.py runserver` we're talking about, you *have to* reset your server to see code changes to reload python and your code into memory.

Only the django devlopment server can detect changes and re-boot for you.

If you are saying you have to reboot the **machine** to update code, then you should look at how to restart your fastcgi process.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#stopping-the-fastcgi-daemon
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#restarting-the-spawned-server

As for the best way? I develop on my local machine so for me a deployment script would ensure I get the latest update from version control and a reboot. Otherwise I just type `arestart` (a one hand typable bash alias).

Comment: +1 this is almost certainly the problem. If it's not, make sure you don't have etags misconfigured and are doing a full refresh on the page.

Comment: Yuji so you are using the same shell script from the 1st link?

Comment: @itgorilla No, I'm not using FastCGI, but yes that restart script should work. It's a simple one to follow, run django with `manage.py runfcgi pidfile=mypidfile.pid`, kill it with 'kill `cat /path/to/mypidfile.pid`'

Comment: thank you for your advise. By the way, Argentinian wines are great :).